# MySQL - scheduled task

Tags: mysql

my requirement is. On every insert of a record (which contains a timestamp & status fields in it), I should schedule a task based on the timestamp and update the status value. Please help me with this. Is there any way to use procedure,events,trigger and gt this done?

Comment: Just use a trigger to set up an event. I fail to see the difficulty. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html |  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Comment: @Polynomial You cannot create or alter event from the trigger.

Comment: @Devart Really? I'm sure I've done something like this before. Perhaps I used a cron job and an events table to implement it...

Comment: @Polynomial I mean that it is impossible to execute CREATE EVENT or ALTER EVENT statements from the trigger body.

Comment: @Polynomial But I think, that UDF might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_name
AFTER INSERT ON Your_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Another_table VALUES(new.status ,curtime()/* fields you need */);
END
```